# check valid url to play in avplayercontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I have three urls and have to check if these urls have a video link to play or not. I have to esc link if it does not contain video in url and play video from next url. This following code will help to track the playing state.

```
let playerAV = AVPlayerViewController()
  var player = AVPlayer()
  playerAV.player = player
  playerAV.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,  self.videoView.frame.width,  self.videoView.frame.height)
  self.addChildViewController(playerAV)
  self.videoView.addSubview(playerAV.view)
  playerAV.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
  playerAV.player?.play()
  addObserverOfMoviePlayer()

 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ChannelDetailViewController.notificationObserver(_:)), name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification , object: player.currentItem)
    _ = UIDevice.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ChannelDetailViewController.deviceOrientationDidChange(_:)) , name:
      UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    playerAV.player!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rate", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
    playerAV.player!.currentItem!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferEmpty", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
    playerAV.player!.currentItem!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackLikelyToKeepUp", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {

    if keyPath == "rate"   {

      if let rate = change?[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as? Float {
        if playerAV.player!.currentItem!.status == AVPlayerItemStatus.ReadyToPlay{
          if rate != 0 && playerAV.player!.error == nil {

            print("normal playback")
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(ChannelDetailViewController.somAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

          }
          else{
            timer?.invalidate()
            print("movie player stopped")
          }

        }else if playerAV.player!.currentItem?.status == AVPlayerItemStatus.Unknown{
          timer?.invalidate()
          print("not ready to play")
        }
      }
    }
    if keyPath == "playbackBufferEmpty"{

      if playerAV.player?.currentItem?.playbackBufferEmpty == true{
        timer?.invalidate()
        print("movie player stopped due to no buffer")
      }
    }

    if keyPath == "playbackLikelyToKeepUp" {

      if playerAV.player?.currentItem?.playbackLikelyToKeepUp == true{

        print("movie player playing after enough data in buffer")
        playerAV.player?.play()

      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just check the length of the video if it's invalid the length will return as zero with this code :

```
let assets = AVAsset(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
let length=Float(assets.duration.value)/Float(assets.duration.timescale)
if length != 0.0  {
// play it
}
```

If you have still problem you can ask me anytime.

Comment: you mean i need to pass video url in let assets = AVAsset(URL: myurl) ?? i need to play from remote not from local..does it check remote url too??

Comment: Yep it will work for both for remote only do this  let assets = AVAsset(URL: myurl) the url will be asset and check the length of it like above.

Comment: If my answer helps you please "Up MArk "

Comment: what if it's an m3u8 url say for a live stream where the length is indeterminate?

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 15 you can use the `isPlayable` property on `AVAsset`. Like this:

```
let asset = AVAsset(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
guard asset.isPlayable else {
   return
}
```